# CKEDITOR add image

Tags: javascript, html, image, ckeditor, base64

I want to add a image to the content of a textarea (replaced by CKEDITOR).

What I have is a script, that takes the image uploaded, and transforms it to BASE64 (after downsizing it).

And I know, that the textarea of CKEDITOR is able to show images (as there is the possibility to insert images via url). But actually nothing I tried is working.

So I have a textarea with the ID `editor`and I replace it by `var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor');`.

What I tried is `$('#editor').append('<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,.........)`, not working. I also tried iit with
`editor.insertHTML()`but that doesn't work as well....

What I tried now, is to insert the base64-string in the url input of CKEDITOR (when adding an image), that worked. So does anybody know how I can do that? Either by just appending an image with the base64 as src, or by inserting the base64-string as url for the built in image upload function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do it:

`CKEDITOR.instances.editor.insertHtml('<img src="' + base64string + '">');`.

This did the trick for me, so actually working with insertHtml, but by acccessing CKEDITOR.instances.editor, and not by the var, declared when replacing the editor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55298230/ckeditor-is-undefined-in-angular-6 Can anyone check this